# Is it really OK to do object closeing/disposing in __del__?

Tags: python

I have been thinking about how I write classes in Python. More specifically how the constructor is implemented and how the object should be destroyed. I don't want to rely on CPython's reference counting to do object cleanup. This basically tells me I should use with statements to manage my object life times and that I need an explicit close/dispose method (this method could be called from `__exit__` if the object is also a context manager).

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def close(self):
        pass
```

Now, if all my objects behave in this way and all my code uses with statements or explicit calls to `close()` (or `dispose()`) I don't realy see the need for me to put any code in `__del__`. Should we really use `__del__` to dispose of our objects?

Comment: I don't want to rely on CPython's reference counting to do object cleanup. Why on earth not?  What's wrong with object reference counting?

Comment: @S.Lott, reference counting is just not there if you move your code to an environment with more advanced garbage collection, such as Jython or IronPython -- and what if one day CPython (e.g. via Unladen Swallow) gets dragged kicking and screaming into the 21st century, too?  I agree with the OP about "not relying" on RC in my reusable, portable libraries (as opposed to one-use, throw-away, scripts and minor modules).

Comment: @S.Lott: Alex already answered your question. Another good reason for wanting to not rely on reference counting is the JIT coming out of the PyPy project. The people behind it seems te be optimistic that it will be able to deliver substatial speed ups compared to CPython.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer : No.

Long answer: Using `__del__` is tricky, mainly because it's not guaranteed to be called. That means you can't do things there that absolutely has to be done. This in turn means that `__del__` basically only can be used for cleanups that would happen sooner or later anyway, like cleaning up resources that would be cleaned up when the process exits, so it doesn't matter if `__del__` doesn't get called. Of course, these are also generally the same things Python will do for you. So that kinda makes `__del__` useless.

Also, `__del__` gets called when Python garbage collects, and you didn't want to wait for Pythons garbage collecting, which means you can't use `__del__` anyway.

So, don't use `__del__`. Use `__enter__/__exit__` instead.

FYI: Here is an example of a non-circular situation where the destructor did not get called:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructing A')

    def __del__(self):
        print('Destructing A')

class B(object):
    a = A()
```

OK, so it's a class attribute. Evidently that's a special case. But it just goes to show that making sure `__del__` gets called isn't straightforward. I'm pretty sure I've seen more non-circular situations where `__del__` isn't called.

Comment: I asked a similar question a year ago. So far, no one has been able to name a legitimate scenario in which the `__del__` method would be of any use at all. As far as I'm concerned, the method should never have been in Python in the first place. It's good for nothing and gives people the false impression that they could use it for cleanup.

Answer (score 8):

Not necessarily.  You'll encounter problems when you have cyclic references.  Eli Bendersky does a good job of explaining this in his blog post:

- [Safely using destructors in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/)

Comment: unfortunately the article linked draws a wrong conclusion. `__del__` is not guaranteed to get called. At all. It’s not only for cyclical references. Also, it says **"Cyclic references, however, are often a sign of bad design"** WTF?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you will not go into cyclic references, then using `__del__` in that way is OK: as soon as the reference count goes to zero, the CPython VM will call that method and destroy the object.

If you plan to use cyclic references - please think it very thoroughly, and check if weak references may help; in many cases, cyclic references are a first symptom of bad design.

If you have no control on the way your object is going to be used, then using `__del__` may not be safe.

If you plan to use JPython or IronPython, `__del__` is unreliable at all, because final object destruction will happen at garbage collection, and that's something you cannot control.

In sum, in my opinion, `__del__` is usually perfectly safe and good; however, in many situation it could be better to make a step back, and try to look at the problem from a different perspective; a good use of try/except and of with contexts may be a more pythonic solution.