# bulk insert class object

Tags: python

I have a situation where I have to insert a lot of records into the table. I have wrapped the insert stuff in a member function(of an object). But it takes a lot of time. To optimize this, I am keeping all these records in a buffer(as a list) as a data member of the class. When the no. of records reaches to 100, I am doing a bulk insert.

Here is the code.

```
class TabDailyQuotes:

    def __init__(self, metadata):
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.indexes = Table('DailyQuotes', metadata, autoload=True)
        self.ins_buf = []
        self.ins = self.indexes.insert()

    def insert(self, dict_data):
        if isinstance(dict_data, types.DictType):
            for key, val in dict_data.items():
                self.ins_buf.append(val)
        else:
            self.ins_buf.append(dict_data)
        if len (self.ins_buf) == 100:
            self.ins.execute(self.ins_buf)
            self.ins_buf = []

    def __del__(self):
        if len (self.ins_buf) > 0:
            self.ins.execute(self.ins_buf)
            self.ins_buf = []
```

Here the problem is that when I call the function for the insert of only one record (and subsequent call to insert subsequent records), I have to use `__del__()` magic function to insert all left over records at the end of life of the object.

Can anybody tell me a better way to deal with this ?

Comment: I don't understand this 0% ? Can you explain me ?

Comment: People will be more eager to answer, if they can expect more points, which they will get when you accept their answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed __del__ will ever be called. So it's best to be explicit about the clean up action and define a distinct method for it, then call it when the program shuts down or the TabDailyQuotes object goes out of scope.

References:

[I don't understand this python __del__ behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104535/i-dont-understand-this-python-del-behaviour)
[Is it really OK to do object closeing/disposing in __del__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111505/is-it-really-ok-to-do-object-closeing-disposing-in-del?rq=1)

Comment: I understand del() magic function is not reliable. I want to get rid of this function. Is there any way to do all these things in a reliable way ?

Comment: @lipun4u As I said, do it explicitly.